# How can I couch the CKEditor inline output in custom surrounding HTML with custom CSS files?

Tags: ckeditor, styles, customization, preview, ckeditor4.x

So let's say that I have the following source in the CKEditor:

```
<p>This is my <b>description</b> content.</p>
```

When this is saved. I know that it will go into a content block on my web site, something like the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="//styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="heading">{{ heading }}</div>
      <div id="description">{{ description }}</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And let's say that the file `styles.css` has the following rule:

```
#description p {
  text-indent: 15px;
}
#description b {
  font-size: larger;
}
```

What I would like to do is to be able to see, as I'm typing, what things are going to look like on the site. Now I'm sure this could be done piecemeal by inserting these styles into the editor manually, but that's not going to work, as our site styles are considerably more complex and vary depending on which site we are on. What I need to be able to do is surround what's in the editor with the tags below, so that what's in the CSS file will naturally take effect in the editor display, giving our editors a realistic expectation of what they will see once their stories are up on the site.

In short, I need something like this:

```
cke.before_code = '<html><head><link href="//styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head><body><div id="content"><div id="description">';
cke.after_code = '</div></div></body></html>';
```

And then I would expect the output that would be seen to be this:

```
before_code + "whatever the editor is typing presently" + after_code
```

Hopefully all that's clear. If anyone has any tips as to how this might be accomplished, would much appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a way to integrate html / styling in the way that I had asked for above. And given the radio silence on this issue, I suspect that what I've asked for here may not be possible. I did, however, figure out a way to achieve the next best thing using the preview button. Depending on the item our editors are editing, clicking the preview button will now show an instant preview for that particular item, styled as if it were live on our sites. Here's a step-by-step for those interested.

First, assume we have the following to start:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor', config);
```

Second, We'll want to add the following to the `config` and place it before the line above so that the event is registered to the editor:

```
Object.assign(config, {
  on: {
    contentPreview: function(e) {
      let match = e.data.dataValue.match(/<body[^>]*>((?:.|\s)*)<\/body>/),
        before = '' +
          '<html>' +
            '<head>' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body>',
        content = match[1],
        after = '' +
            '</body>' +
          '</html>;
      e.data.dataValue = before + content + after;
    }
  }
});
```

`content` will now contain whatever the user has entered in the editor. And by adding `before`, `content`, and `after` together, we end up with the web page that will be presented in the preview. Only now, the page is under our control, and we can make adjustments based on what page the editor is viewing, other fields on the page, and so on, and we can add in links to our site's live styles.

Let's say that I now want to add in Bootstrap and a link to my site's styling. And let's say I want to surround content with one type of container if an editor is working on a blog and another if he is working on a news story. In this case, I might do something like this:

```
Object.assign(config, {
  on: {
    contentPreview: function(e) {
      let match = e.data.dataValue.match(/<body[^>]*>((?:.|\s)*)<\/body>/),
        before = '' +
          '<html>' +
            '<head>' +
              '<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' +
              '<link href="//mylivesite.com/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">' +
              '<script src="//mylivesite.com/scripts.js"></' + 'script>' +
            '</head>' +
            '<body>',
        content = match[1],
        after = '' +
            '</body>' +
          '</html>;
      if (location.pathname.indexOf('blog') > -1)
        content = '' +
          '<div class="row blog">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-8">' + content + '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-4">Blog Right Column Content</div>' +
          '</div>';
      else
        content = '' +
          '<div class="row news">' +
            '<div class="col-sm-8">' + content + '</div>' +
            '<div class="col-sm-4">News Right Column Content</div>' +
          '</div>';
      e.data.dataValue = before + content + after;
    }
  }
});
```

Now when the preview opens, it will have all the styling from the live site as well as bootstrap columns, so the editor can play with the browser and see how everything will look at various dimensions.

In a sense then, this is superior to just seeing styles in the editor as you type (although that still would be nice), since it allows editors to get a sense of what the content will look like in the context of the page on which it appears after styles have loaded and scripts executed. And if content will appear differently based upon which options the editor has selected, you can build the preview page dynamically based on those values prior to presenting the preview.

This was the solution I ended up with, and my people were very pleased with it, so I thought I would share.